# Ubuntu 19.04 crashes when sending files/directories from Dekstop to Trash

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, crash, trash, desktop-icons

I'm new with Ubuntu (and Linux in general), and I have noticed something that was really bothering me, which is the fact that when I try to move files from my Desktop to the Trash, my OS either crashes (closes everything and reboots), or it freezes for a short time.

Can anyone help me know why it happens?